# Passing CSV into PHP to Encode multiple rows in JSON

Tags: php, json, csv, postman

[Postman is an IDE for making APIs in Chrome.](https://www.getpostman.com/)

I have the route defined as:

[image]

With logic in the PHP case statement as:

```
case "checkContactsWithServer":

        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password, $gcmregid)) 
        {   
            $phoneNumCSV = $_REQUEST['phone_num_csv'];

            $syncContactsServerSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT
                                      source_user_sync_id, target_user_sync_id, friend_request_sync_id, status, user_sync_id, phone_number
                                    FROM friends a
                                    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT distinct
                                                  user_sync_id,
                                                  phone_number
                                                FROM users
                                                WHERE phone_number IN ('".$phoneNumCSV."')
                                                AND user_sync_id != '".$userId."'
                                                ) b
                                      ON a.target_user_sync_id = '".$userId."'
                                      AND a.source_user_sync_id = b.user_sync_id                                      
                                      OR a.source_user_sync_id = '".$userId."'
                                      AND a.target_user_sync_id = b.user_sync_id;";

            if($result = $db->query($syncContactsServerSQL))
            {

                $rows = array();

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $rows[] = array('data' => $row);
                }

                // now all the rows have been fetched, it can be encoded
                echo json_encode($rows);    

            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;          
            }       


        }
        else
        {
            error_log($out, 0);
            $out = FAILED;
        }


    break;
```

As can be seen above, passing in the two phone numbers as a CSV, ie. "number1,number2", the JSON result is only one object. But running the query in the db, returns two, as it should:

[image]

I know I am missing something simple here. How can I configure this to work?

Comment: I had to reverse image search your screenshot just to figure out that this is something called "postman." your entire question you didn't once mention the name of the software you're asking for help with. good luck..

Comment: Using postman just allows sending organized requests to your server to test,  nothing special

Comment: alright then, how bout tagging SQL.. seems like a sql issue to me

Comment: Your php code is ripe for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your query. Your `IN` clause is all freaked up.

```
WHERE phone_number IN ('".$phoneNumCSV."')
```

Becomes...

```
WHERE phone_number IN ('1231231234,1231231234')
```

The correct syntax is

```
WHERE phone_number IN ('1231231234','1231231234')
```

You can achieve this by changing this line..

```
$phoneNumCSV = $_REQUEST['phone_num_csv'];
```

To this..

```
$phoneNumCSV = "'".implode("','", explode(",", $_REQUEST['phone_num_csv']))."'";
```

and then removing the quotes in the query.

```
WHERE phone_number IN ($phoneNumCSV)
```

(You don't need the double quotes or the dots either)

Also, you should use some kind of prepared statement or at least escape user input.